# insert a jpg image inside HTML rotating 3d object

Tags: 3d

Is it possible to insert a jpg bitmap or svg image inside of HTML5 3d objects??

the 3d objects are this ones:

http://www.script-tutorials.com/triangle-mesh-for-3d-objects-in-html5

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the process of adding an image to a 3D object is called texturing.

I know very little about 3D in HTML5, but here is a tutorial about the subject.

http://www.gamedevacademy.org/3d-objects-with-textures-using-html5-babylonjs-series-part-4/